# python syntaxerror

Tags: python

I just start learn python, and the code has some error, can't run. so can you help me address it. it shows

```
File "ex2.py", line 21
if isRobotRecord(line)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### ex2.py

```
import time
robot_emails = ["googlebot@google.com"]
robot_emails.append("66.249.74.228")
robot_emails.append("61.147.110.22")
robot_emails.append("61.147.110.21")
robot_emails.append("61.147.112.231")
f = open("/opt/CLiMB/Storage1/log/vsftp.log")
def isRobotRecord(line):
    for email in robot_emails:
            if email in line.split("Client")[1]:
                    return False
    return True
def OnlyRecent(line):
    if  time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")> time.gmtime(time.time()-(60*60*24*7)):
        return True
    return False
filename= time.strftime('%Y%m%d')+'.log'
f1= open(filename,'w')
for line in f:
    if OnlyRecent(line):
            if isRobotRecord(line)
                    print line
                    f1.write(line)
f.close()
f1.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum, you need a `:` at the end of that `if` statement. That's what's causing your error, similar to the following transcript:

```
pax> cat good.py 
for plugh in (1,2,3):
    print plugh

pax> python good.py 
1
2
3

pax> cat bad.py 
for plugh in (1,2,3)
    print plugh

pax> python bad.py 
  File "bad.py", line 1
    for plugh in (1,2,3)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You may also want to look into your indentation - it looks like that `if`  statement may be indented one too many times. There are *eight* spaces difference between it and the previous line despite the fact you appear to be using *four* most everywhere else.

In a language where indentation is so important, you have to be particularly careful.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a colon at the end of that line:

```
if isRobotRecord(line):
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ':' character end of every lines starting with if,else,elif,while,for,def,class etc. In addition I advice you that try to obey [this](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html) rules while writing python